# 'URI is not hierarchical' when loading a file from a .jar

Tags: java

I'm working on a `Java` based `OpenGL` project, which needs to load textures at runtime.
It's a `Maven` managed project and when packaged all files are placed inside one `.jar`.

I have the following piece of code which tries to load a texture:

```
URL url = Utils.class.getResource("/car.jpg");
TextureIO.newTexture(new File(url.toURI()), false);
```

That code works fine if I run the project from within `Eclipse`, but when packaged and executed from command line I get the following error (which is referring to the second line above):

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical
```

How can that line be re-written so the `URI` is correct, assuming I need to use `getResourceAsStream()`, but I need to pass it's value into a `new File()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access it as a File, but when you package it in a jar there is no car.jpg file anymore, it is zipped inside the jar file.

So, you can't crate a File object pointing to it, the URL in this case is not a normal file URL but a "special" file-inside-the-jar URL.

Java is able to decode these URLs, or to access the resource directly and give you an InputStream.

The newTexture method also accepts either directly the URL or an InputStream.

To use the URL :

```
TextureIO.newTexture(url, false,"jpg");
```

To use the input stream :

```
InputStream instr = null;
try {
  instr = Utils.class.getResourceAsStream("/car.jpg");
  TextureIO.newTexture(instr, false, "jpg");
} finally {
  instr.close();
}
```

Comment: Didn't realize `TextureIO.newTexture` could accept an `InputStream`, went with that approach.